# Soundcloud song names

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm new to VBA web scraping and html structure in general and I'm having some trouble getting the song names off this html address "https://soundcloud.com/maraudamusic/tracks"

This is what I have tried so far and I can't seem to pull the `<li>` song names from the html document (I barely know what I'm talking about so forgive me).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SCScrape()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim site As String
Dim artist As String

artist = "maraudamusic"
site = "https://soundcloud.com/" & artist & "/tracks"

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate site

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set html = New HTMLDocument

Dim ul As IHTMLElementCollection
'Dim ul As Variant
'Dim li As IHTMLListElement
Dim els As Variant
Dim el As Variant
'Dim li As Variant

'Set ul = html.getElementsByClassName("lazyLoadingList__list sc-list-nostyle sc-clearfix")
'Set ul = html.getElementsByTagName("ul")
Set els = html.getElementsByClassName("soundTitle_usernameTitleContainer")
Debug.Print

For Each el In els
    Debug.Print el.innerHTML
Next el

Debug.Print "Hello"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is trying to read elements from a blank document...

You set **html = New HTMLDocument**. This instantiates the html object as a blank HTMLDocument object.

What you should do is **set html = ie.document** to read the contents of the current document in the IE window.

Also, as Soundcloud is a Javascript/AJAX type application, you may need to wait a couple of seconds for AJAX calls to finish. This may not be necessary but I find it sometimes helps.

Here's a working example.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SCScrape()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Dim site As String
    Dim artist As String

    artist = "maraudamusic"
    site = "https://soundcloud.com/" & artist & "/tracks"

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate site

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")) ' wait for ajax...

    Set html = ie.Document  'get the document from IE

    Dim els As Variant
    Dim el As Variant

    Set els = html.getElementsByClassName("soundTitle__title")

    For Each el In els
        Debug.Print el.innerText
    Next el

    Debug.Print "Hello"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer this helps so much! How were you able to determine that Soundcloud is a Javascript/AJAX type application?

Comment: @Brian When there page first loads there is a 'loading' spinner where the tracks should be or if you look at the source of the page you will see there is minimal HTML because this is loaded later via AJAX. Or you can have a look at the network panel of your dev tools and filter by XHR requests you will see calls to the Soundcloud API for track names, comments, etc.